# rails pagination nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, nested-routes

I am attempting to put a `contacts` paginated partial inside of a view for `rooftops`.  Rooftops has many contacts and also has a nested route allowing `/rooftops/1/contacts`.  When I try to create the `will_paginate` links I get `/rooftops/1` as the path rather than '/rooftops/1/contacts/'.

Is there a way to modify the pagination path with out creating my own pagination link view?  I have tried going to the rdoc for will_paginate [here](http://gitrdoc.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/master/) but it goes to a godaddy page.

Any ideas?

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parents
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rooftops
  has_one :user
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :phone, :as => :phoneable, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :position
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:street].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:phone_number].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  validates_associated :address, :phone, :position
  validates_presence_of :lname 
  validates_presence_of :fname 
  validates_presence_of :email 
  validates_presence_of :position_id

  def self.search(page)
    paginate  :per_page => 3,
              :page => page
  end
end

class RooftopsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @rooftop = Rooftop.find(params[:id])
    @contacts = @rooftop.contacts.search(1)
  end
end

<div class='pagination'>
  <%= will_paginate contacts %>
</div>
```

This creates `/rooftops/1` and I'm not sure how to force it to `/rooftops/1/contacts`.

---------------------EDIT---------------------

My routes is

```
resources :rooftops do
  resources :contacts
end
```

I think I know where my problem is.  Since my search function is within the model.  I never actually touch the `contacts` controller.  I do the search from the `rooftops` controller and call a partial from the `contacts` view.  I'll show what my views are.

```
<div id='contacts' style='margin-top: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;'>
  <h4>Contacts <%= link_to "new", new_polymorphic_path([@rooftop, Contact]) %></h4>

 <%= render :partial => 'contacts/contacts', :locals => { :object_type => @rooftop, :layer => 1 } %>
</div>
```

This is the actual partial.  As you can see, it never really goes through the contacts controller.  Could this be the source of my problem?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
 <tr>
  <td class='contact_mailer'>
   <%= link_to image_tag('icons/gray_light/mail_12x9.png'), "mailto:#{contact.email}" %>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div class='expandable layer_<%= layer %>' style='float: left'>
    <%= link_to contact.fname.titleize + ' ' + contact.lname.titleize, polymorphic_path([object_type, @contact]), :class => "contact_name" %>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= image_tag 'icons/blue/key_stroke_8x8.png' %>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>

<br />
<div class='pagination'>
  <%= will_paginate @contacts %>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the github wiki page of mislav/will_pageinate and the documentation is probably the same, try it here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki

Answer (score 1):

There are several places where you could go wrong. Perhaps you don't have your routes set correctly. The `will_paginate` call should be in the contacts view, it it there? It is not clear from the snippet you gave.

The `self.search` method in the `Contact` model is very curious for me, this should be rather in the controller. It makes sense, the search method is related to the control of the `Contact`. And have it as an instance method.

The route `rooftops/:id/contacts` should lead to Contact controller. You might check whether it is so.

I suppose you need something like this:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your model definition, validations
  # no self.search method here
  cattr_reader :per_page
  @@per_page = 3
end

class RooftopsController < ApplicationController
  # your RooftopsController methods
  # the show you listed should be in ContactsController
end

class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # I guess you have contacts for Rooftop
    @contacts = Rooftop.find(params[:id]).contacts
    # you paginate the array of results
    @contacts.paginate(params[:page])
  end

## This is in the view of the Contacts#show
<div class='pagination'>
  <%= will_paginate contacts %>
</div>
```

You probably need to paginate on an array. This is simple to do, please refer to [this](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2008/06/how-to-use-will_paginate-with-non-activerecord-collectionarray/). Hope this helped.